# Jenkins allow unsafe plugin

Tags: jenkins

I'm setting up a new Jenkins instance on a closed network. I would like for the Jenkins build-server to be able to use the Grails plugin. The plugin however does not show under available plugins.

I think it is because of the following: https://jenkins.io/security/advisory/2017-04-10/ that states that the plugin is unsafe.

Inspecting http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json shows then plugin, but only in regards to the security warning:

```
    {
        "id": "SECURITY-458",
        "message": "Arbitrary code execution vulnerability",
        "name": "grails",
        "type": "plugin",
        "url": "https://jenkins.io/security/advisory/2017-04-10/",
        "versions": [
            {
                "pattern": ".*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Is there any way to force Jenkins to be able to download and use this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I think this message mean that your can`t download from Jenkins repository.
But you can get sources from [GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci/grails-plugin) and build this plugin by you own.
Or you can try [my build](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-tiw0QHssidTFBLdDBrRmhrNmc/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force Jenkins to download unsafe plugins, but you can install them manually.

Download any plugin (even unsafe ones) from their [Artifactory repo](https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/releases/org/jenkins-ci/plugins).

[More information](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/04/10/security-advisory/) why unsafe plugins are not distributed anymore.